# How to use Tensorflows GradientTape() to compute biases

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking to implement GradientTape() on a custom NN architecture but I don't see an explanation anywhere on how to use this to compute biases. A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814376/gradient-calculation-for-bias-term-using-gradienttape), but it was not answered fully.

As a simple example, I have the training step for my NN like so:

```
self.W = ## Initialized earlier on
self.b = ## Initialized earlier on

@tf.function
    def train(self):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = self.feedforward()
            loss = self.loss_evaluation()
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, self.W)
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, self.b) ## How do I do this?

        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.W))
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.b)) ## How do I do this?
```

Put simply, I cannot evaluate the gradients with respect to the biases as nowhere in any documentation or tutorial do I see the bias term included. So, how do I go about implementing the bias term as a trainable variable in my code? I'm not looking to implement this with keras, so do not suggest I use `trainable_variables` as I want to do it from scratch.

Comment: Why wouldn't the code you have here work?

Answer (score 0):

@thushv89 The code Jamie showed doesn't work because you can't call `gradient()` on the same tape twice.

Jamie, why can't you simply do the following?

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = self.feedforward()
    loss = self.loss_evaluation()
grads = tape.gradient(loss, [self.W, self.b])
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [self.W, self.b]))
```